# The same code for client(Angular2) and server(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Is there a way of using the same code for both Anglular2 models and mongoose models on express.js? The same question goes for Angular2 validation forms and express.js validation post requests(obviously one have to check the data twice on the client and on the server). 
I moved from php to nodejs in hopes to avoid duplicate code. So how do I exactly do this?

Comment: In what context?  Do you mean server side rendering or do you mean client and server modules that can be used in both contexts?

Comment: the latter. And I don't get these dislikes. I thought one of the points of full js development was to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: AngularJS is a client side Implementation whereas NodeJS is server side Implemenattion. NodeJS is similar to JAVA/ASP.NET,ETC. There is no way you can use same code.

Comment: Sure, you should be able to post the code you want to reuse as an npm package (either public or private), then install the package in both your server application project, as well as your angular project. Then just import the classes you need from the package.

Comment: I am really confused about people who see my question as a blasphemy. I'm not an idiot. I know that angular is frontend. Nodejs is backend and you can't LITERALLY serve the same code for both. But we have things like transpilers, webpack, SCSS compilation. Those are all tools that are used in production, not in deployment, so why not?

Comment: Let's take for example form validation. First, I need to validate data on the frontend(angular). But there's no way I can pass it to the server(nodejs) without validating the same data the second time.And if something changes, I have to edit the code twice. What's the point of all this "one language on both server and client"? How is it better than any other backend server on java, php etc? I know that nodejs is good for chats and asynchronous stuff but my question is about the "benefit from the re-usability of code and the lack of context switching"(c)

Comment: You might find Nest.JS interesting. It was heavily inspired by Angular. https://github.com/nestjs/nest

Comment: In other serverside or php  framework you are preparing form in server side so you dont need to validate two times or write a code two times but this is era where the front-end is most fertile land in the world, you dont need to keep server busy on this kind of stuff or send a number of request just for validating form or creating html template in server side. You can cook everything in front-end after satisfying you can send it to serve but just because of security issue you can do validation there also but its not like that you hv to send request again and again for single form submission